# How to use multiple content in jQuery animated popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my website under team web page I'm using a animated popup to see the the profile summary for each member. But when I place the popup button under each person, I'm getting the same content for all the persons. How can I use different content with single popup?

When I search in google, people are saying need to change in jQuery. I'm not familiar with jQuery.

Here is my Java and HTML scripts

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
  var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass(buttonId);
  $('body').addClass('modal-active');
});

$('#modal-container').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('out');
  $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
});
```

```html
    <section id="team">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="heading text-center col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1200ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
          <h1>The Team</h1>
          <h2>Awesome Support</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="team-members">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-member wow flipInY" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
              <div class="member-image">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/team/1.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="member-info">
                <h3>test</h3>
                <h4>test</h4>
                <p>test content</p>
     <!--/Animate Button-->
    <div class="content">
     <div class="buttons">
    <div id="seven" class="button">Bond</div>
   </div>
   </div>
    </div>
              <div class="social-icons">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="linkedin" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="dribbble" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="rss" href="#"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-member wow flipInY" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="500ms">
              <div class="member-image">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/team/2.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="member-info">
                <h3>test</h3>
                <h4>test</h4>
                <p>test content</p>
              </div>
     
     <div class="content">
     <div class="buttons">
    <div id="seven" class="button">Bond</div>
   </div>
   </div>
     
     
              <div class="social-icons">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="linkedin" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="dribbble" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="rss" href="#"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-member wow flipInY" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="800ms">
              <div class="member-image">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/team/3.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="member-info">
                <h3>test</h3>
                <h4>test</h4>
                <p>test content</p>
              </div>
              <div class="social-icons">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="linkedin" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="dribbble" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="rss" href="#"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-member wow flipInY" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="1100ms">
              <div class="member-image">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/team/4.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="member-info">
                <h3>test</h3>
                <h4>test</h4>
                <p>test content</p>
              </div>
     <!--/ Button execute script-->
     
     <div id="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-background">
      <div class="modal">
     <h2>I'm a Modal</h2>
     <p>Hear me roar.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>
     
              <div class="social-icons">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="linkedin" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="dribbble" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="rss" href="#"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
  </div>
      </div>            
    </div>
  </section><!--/#team-->
```

Comment: Please try to make a note of edits made to your prior questions, so that the same edits are unnecessary on your newer ones. Capital "I" when referring to yourself, and try to omit "please help me" - we know you need help, and it rather sounds like begging. Keep it succinct please!

Comment: @halfer fine. can you share any scripts to use animated popup for each team members.? i tried in google and couldn't get anything.